Installing Chart.js on Statamic (Laravel Herd) results in Error 404
I am trying to get myself started with Chart.js on statamic (with Laravel Herd), currently trying to run their step-by-step guide to no avail.
I did:

Create a site locally (which works).
npm install chart.js
Uncommented/added rows in the vite.config.js file as per the help. What I get is:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue2 from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/site.css',
                'resources/js/site.js',
                'node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js',
                'node_modules/chart.js/auto/auto.js'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue2(),
    ],
});


npm run dev

After that, on Chrome and Firefox, I get an error Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "chart.js/auto". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"..
When I change the line import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'; as per the above, the error becomes:GET [...]chart.js/auto net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

What is the correct relative or absolute URL to reach the JS module?
More generally speaking, is there a way to check the mapping between the file system and the URL a resource will be provided through?When talking about a page to be rendered, there is a field in the control panel of statamic but for that sort of external resource, I am lost.


Where are you importing Chart?
